# How to modify GEM_PATH without explicitly modifying environment variable

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wonder what is the best way to run ruby with defined path to gems **without** setting GEM_PATH explicitly.

So, basically I wonder whether it possible to do this:

```
ruby --some-magic-gem-path my/gems script.rb
```

instead of this:

```
export GEM_PATH=my/gems
ruby script.rb
unset GEM_PATH
```

My first thought was: "A-ha, I just can do something like `ruby -r rubygems -e "Gem.path << 'my/gems'"` script.rb" but then I realized that `script.rb` in this case won't run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use the `-e` flag in Ruby to `unshift` your folder where gems should be searched for.

```
$ ruby -e 'Gem.path.unshift("~/bin")' -e "p Gem.path"
["~/bin", "/home/vgoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247", "/home/vgoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"]
```

I think though that this still won't allow you to run the program.

So, it may be better to include the file that has your custom need in it using `-r custom_gem_path.rb` rather than invoking the `-e` flag.

```
ruby -r./custom_gem_path.rb test.rb
```

This gives me the same output as above, given that what in the first `-e` argument is stored in `./custom_gem_path.rb`.

Comment: thank you for this answer. So, basically this means there's nothing easier and more elegant than modifying global environment variable, ok.